# Android Database Insert At The Beginning

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I want to insert required data for my application at the beginning and I will use these data. And I want to insert once, and there must be no duplicate. Therefore, in "onCreate", I'm doing like that : if the row count of table(such as student etc) is 0, I'm inserting students. I don't think it's the best way to do this. Therefore I want to learn if there is a better way.

Comment: Does "at the beginning" mean when the user starts any arbitrary session of using the app, or does it mean the first time ever that the app is used?

Comment: I mean after the installation. Data will be inserted during installation of app and after that when user starts the app, there must not be insert operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your database populated at install time and never any other time, your only reasonable option is to package your pre-populated database with your APK as a built-in resource.  This has the advantage of simplifying your app.

Alternately, if you implement the [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for your database, anything you insert during `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` will only ever be inserted either on the first run of you app or when someone clears all your app's data (which is more or less putting you back to a fresh install anyway).  The `SQLiteOpenHelper` superclass knows whether or not to run the creation code when you call one of the `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadOnlyDatabase()` methods to get your database reference.

It is worth noting that Android doesn't really let you run an installer the way desktop software does.  If you need to do any setup work, you need to be able to detect and remember when your app has been run before.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply. Could you give an example for the first option? I'm using SQLiteOpenHelper and inserting data in "onCreate" of my main activity. Therefore, it always inserts the same data when the app starts.

Comment: You would create a SQLite database file during your build process and include it as a [raw resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).  Check in that table for more information.

Comment: You need to put your insert statements in the `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)` call of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation.  That is almost certainly where you have your table create statements.  Do your data inserts in the same place, and you'll only do the inserts when the database file is created for the first time.